# Find fishing bobber "owner" in Minecraft 1.16

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm attempting to allow someone to use a fishing rod and essentially make an ore buster. I'm just not sure how I would be able to efficiently find the user of said fishing rod and perform the rest of the actions I need for the ore buster, *without* also letting it happen to other, normal fishing rods.

The following are different ways I've thought of, and reasons why they may not work and/or why I've had trouble with them;

1. Using the player's `SelectedItem` to see if they're holding a specific fishing rod, then test for fishing bobbers near them while it's active. For one, `SelectedItem` has always been unclear, and the [data values section for the Player on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player#Data_values) doesn't tell you. It simply says "See Item Format" then sends you to a dead section.
2. Simply testing for a fishing bobber near the player. This is simple, but prevents people from using normal fishing rods as well.

Comment: Don't worry, your title was super clear to me!

Comment: Could you try adding custom lore to the specific fishing rod, and searching if such the lore is on any item nearby?

Comment: The issue is that would still require use of `SelectedItem` to verify, and as I said, that's never been clear to me and the wiki doesn't give any information on it.

Comment: I've fixed the dead section link, for what it's worth.